# GBP sign as price range in JSON-LD

Tags: schema.org

I am using the `priceRange` [property](https://schema.org/priceRange) in a local business. My locality is England so using GBP as price symbols. So I have added `££` but it is rendering as below:

`"priceRange": "��"`

If I use `&pound;` that doesn't solve it either. What's the solution?

Comment: What encoding are you using on your page?

Comment: I'm using UTF-8 `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` changing it to `<meta charset="UTF-8">` didn't solve it either. Is this the correct encoding?

Comment: Hmmm...the original should do it.`<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"> `.  It is obviously a character set mismatch but based on what info we have here it is hard to be sure.  Is it displaying OK on the web page?

Comment: I think the file could be in a different encoding than that stated in the html. See if your editor has the ability to change the encoding of the file itself. Or try a different editor.

Comment: Thanks guy I'll give it a go and see if any changes.

Comment: You haven't said _where_ is it rendering like that. Are you viewing the source HTML from a live page, or what?

Comment: Yes this is the source of a live page, though Google snippet tester doesn't find any errors.

Answer (score 2):

The expected value for the price range property is text. Try to set the value for this property to text but not the characters recommended in the Schema documentation for this property some kind of "genius". For example: *from 10 to 80 UK pounds*.

Comment: What would be the outcome of putting that in? Would search engines recognise that?

Comment: Google recommends using this property https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/local-business